# Showing keyboard moves my components Overlay, i want to hide Bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, android-keypad

Let say I have the following layout,

[image]

when I click on the edit text at the bottom I get this:

[image]

but i want that the bottom should remain fix. and the keyboard will overlay it. so that bottom should hide behind.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the window how to re-size itself with the soft keyboard is shown. You want:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

See the documentation for more details: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN